# What is this plant with deeply-lobed leaves and a taproot?

Tags: identification

While doing some work in the garden we stumbled upon a plant we can't identify.
We already tried using a plant identification app but are unsure of the results.

We had some Papaver in the vicinity that looks kind of similar, but we are unsure if that's really it. We fear it might be some kind of Ragweed.

[image: Picture 1]
[image: Picture 2]

Can any of you help with identifying it?

We are in south-east Germany, the [pictures](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eMMfI.jpg) were taken today.

Comment: Poppy seems very much like it (*Papaver* like you guessed already). Wait for the flowers to be sure.

Comment: Definitely not a ragweed

Answer (score 1):

Without flowers it is a bit hard to tell, I suggest

- [Buck's-horn plantain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plantago_coronopus) (German: *[Krähenfuß-Wegerich](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kr%C3%A4henfu%C3%9F-Wegerich)*) is very abundant, and also a possible candidate.
- It could indeed be [Shirley poppy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shirley_poppy), but wild poppy is rather rare to be found in German gardens unless you cultivated it nearby (which you did).

I am also rather certain that it is *not* [ragweed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ragweed).

PS: https://identify.plantnet.org/ is a great resource which also comes as an [App](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.plantnet&hl=en&gl=US).